# How can I send a pointer to something from one program to another?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have a program which creates objects "Diagram" and fills them with data. After that I try to send the pointer to these objects to diagram.exe so that it would draw diagrams. I use _spawnv, and the pointer that diagram.exe gets differs from the pointer I send. What do I do wrong? And is there a more proper way for this? Thanks in advance.

//this is the program that calls diagram.exe

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
    Diagram** diagrams = new Diagram*[2];
    diagrams[0] = new Diagram(1001, "sin(x)");
    diagrams[1] = new Diagram(150, "atan(x)");
    diagrams[2] = NULL;

    double x = -2.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        diagrams[0]->points[i].x = x;
        diagrams[0]->points[i].y = sin(x);
        diagrams[0]->points[i].flag = true;
        diagrams[0]->points[i].radius = 4;

        diagrams[1]->points[i].x = x;
        diagrams[1]->points[i].y = atan(x);
        diagrams[1]->points[i].flag = true;
        diagrams[1]->points[i].radius = 5;

        x += 0.004;
    }

    cout << "CallDiagram.exe: diagrams: " << (void*)diagrams << endl;

    char* args[3] = {"diagram.exe", (char*)diagrams, NULL};
    _spawnv(_P_WAIT, "..\\..\\diagram\\Debug\\diagram.exe", args);

    _getch();

    delete diagrams[0];
    delete diagrams[1];
    delete [] diagrams;

    return 0;
}
```

//diagram.cpp

```
#include "diagram.h"
#include "DrawDiagram.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc <= 1)
    {
        cout << "\ndiagram.exe: No arguments!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Diagram** diagrams = (Diagram**)argv[1];//NULL;
    cout << "diagram.exe: diagrams: " << (void*)diagrams << endl;
```

[image]

Comment: Remember that the memory map is private to a process, no two processes has the same memory map. You should read about [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) and other [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods.

Comment: If "smth" is supposed to mean "something", it would be clearer if you spelled it out. And the answer is basically "you can't do that". You'll need to find a way to send the actual data.

Comment: As Joachim said, the memory address spaces of two different processes are different. And since a pointer holds a memory address, you can't use a pointer created in one address space in another one. [boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) has a concept of "offset pointers", which could be worth looking into.

Comment: @KeithThompson _'You'll need to find a way to send the actual data.'_ ... or share common address space (e.g. mem mapped file).

Comment: I use a file for that now, but I wanted to find a simplier way to send the data.

Comment: I only don't get one thing — why downvote? A perfectly valid question, well explained. Yes, the OP does not know about virtual addressing and  MMU on modern platforms. But if he did, then he wouldn't have asked a question. His program could even work (in theory) on a system with no MMU. I don't get why downvote.

Comment: @Vorgin To avoid downvotes, you should try narrowing your code boiling down to the actual problem you have, leave aside all that [tag:sdl](?) specific stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send pointers from one program to another. You can create some shared memory, which both of your applications open, and use that to store the data you want shared.

On Windows, youd use [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create such a shared memory, and the second application uses [`OpenFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get hold of it on the other side.

Note that this isn't EASIER than sending data in a file, because you will need to make sure the data is synchronized and fully written to the shared memory before the other part tries to use it.